# Why I am getting an Attribute Error "AttributeError: <class name> object has no attribute 'driver'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

In my Selenium Testing Framework I have used 4 files:

1. conftest.py : to define all my fixtures
2. baseClass.py : to define an empty class where the fixtures can be used and later these classes    can be inherited in the actual test case class
3. test_practice.py: file having the actual test case
4. practicepage.py file : where all the objects of the webpage are defined

conftest.py file content:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup1():
 bdriver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="D:\webdriversselenium\mozilladriver.exe")
 bdriver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/AutomationPractice/")
 bdriver.maximize_window()
 yield
 bdriver.close()
```

baseClass.py file content:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup1")
class baseclass1:
  pass
```

practicepage.py:

```
class pracpage:
  def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver

  input = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#name")

  def inputbox(self):
    return self.driver.find_element(*pracpage.input)
```

test_practice.py:

```
class Testprac(baseclass1):
  def test_practicepage(self):
    pracp = pracpage(self.driver)
    pracp.inputbox().send_keys("Abhinav")
```

I have used chrome as well as firefox browser to run the test but in boith cases i am getting the following error :

> test_practice.py:7 (Testprac.test_practicepage) self =
> <Seleniumframework.tests.test_practice.Testprac object at
> 0x000001F25FDE3F70>
>
> def test_practicepage(self):
>
> > pracp = pracpage(self.driver) E AttributeError: 'Testprac' object has no attribute 'driver'
>
> test_practice.py:9: AttributeError

Comment: Well, `Testprac` indeed has no `driver` attribute, which you try to access with `self.driver`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have created a object pracp from the class pracpage in that particular function.
Please refer class pracpage in the file practicepage.py

Comment: You try to create instance of `pracpage` class exactly on that same line `pracp = pracpage(self.driver)`. Here `self` refers to instance of `Testprac` class. It looks you lack basic understanding of OOP concepts

Comment: I have just started with Python. Can you please suggest what should be the correct way to do that?

Comment: I was following the code of the tutor while doing a course. And the same code worked for him. I have checked for any gaps i  this code but it seems that there is no difference.He has also defined the objects from a different class in the same manner